# Adding Source of Document as Footnote with External Files

Tags: footnotes, external-files

I have a beamer presentation where I am including a set of external slides using `includepdf` from `pdfpages`. I want to be able to add a footnote to each of these external slides, which attributes them to the correct source. Is there a way to do it in LaTeX?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I know that the `pdfpages` has some `pagecommand` option. This here is unsatisfactory, but works for the moment:

```
\includepdf[pages=-,pagecommand={\thispagestyle{empty}\footnote{X}}]{PP.pdf}
```

The problem is that it typesets the small `1` somewhere.

You can surely generate some other kind of overlay over the pdf image. Such an overlay would require some kind of absolute or relative positioning and it would use custom formatting rather than the way `\footnote` works.

I am aware of two approaches for absolute positioning: `tikz` with its `overlay` option or the `textpos` package.

Here is what I found in my notes for the `tikz` approach (copy to your preamble):

```
\tikzset{
    every overlay node/.style={
        draw=black,fill=white,rounded corners,anchor=north west,
    },
}
% Usage:
% \tikzoverlay at (-1cm,-5cm) {content};
% or
% \tikzoverlay[text width=5cm] at (-1cm,-5cm) {content};
\def\tikzoverlay{%
    \tikz[baseline,overlay]\node[every overlay node]
}%
```

This allows you to write

```
\includepdf[pages=-,pagecommand={\thispagestyle{empty}\tikzoverlay at (0cm,-5cm) {copied from somewhere};}]{PP.pdf}%
```

Note that `\tikzoverlay` might be interesting in other occasions as well. For your application, you may want to adjust the `every overlay style` (leave out `draw=black` for example).

The `textpos` package will also do the job, but personally, I always found `tikz` much more flexible, easier to use, and prettier.

Comment: Good job! I was just typing the same answer, just in less detail! BTW, simply indent code blocks by four spaces. You can mark it and press CTRL+K for that. Then you get syntax highlighting.

Comment: @Martin thanks for the hint with CTRL+K. I wasn't aware of that (but syntax highlighting is active when I type it as `<pre><code> ... </code></pre>` as well - isn't it?)

Comment: Didn't worked for me with the HTML tags.